# How to make knn algorithm more efficient

Tags: python, bigdata, knn, kdtree

I have to write a function which classifies points with knn algorithm.
Therefore a train data set is given with up to 20000 points. We have to split this set in 5 subsets and classify every point in each subset with the algorihm for k between 1 and 200
Then we should use the best k to classify a test data set with 5000 points.
The data given can have dimensions up to 20.
Its not allowed to use the kdtree or knn algorithm of python

I used a kd tree to fasten the algorithm but it still needs up to 10 minutes
I tried to implement the kd tree iterative but it was slower.

```
def kNN_search(x, k, node, level, sucher):
dim = x.shape[0]
r = level % dim
distance = np.linalg.norm(x - node.point[1:])

if node.point[0] >= k:
    for j in range(0, k):
        if distance >= sucher.best_distance[j]:
            if j == 0:
                break
            else:
                sucher.best_point[0:(j - 1), :] = sucher.best_point[1:j,      :]
                sucher.best_point[j - 1, :] = node.point

                sucher.best_distance[0:(j - 1)] = sucher.best_distance[1:j]
                sucher.best_distance[j - 1] = distance
                break
    if distance < sucher.best_distance[k - 1]:
        sucher.best_point[0:(k - 1), :] = sucher.best_point[1:k, :]
        sucher.best_point[k - 1, :] = node.point

        sucher.best_distance[0:(k - 1)] = sucher.best_distance[1:k]
        sucher.best_distance[k - 1] = distance
if x[r] <= node.point[r + 1]:  # Zuerst wird die Seite auf der x liegt untersucht
    if x[r] - sucher.best_distance[0] <= node.point[
                r + 1] and node.left != None:  # Aber nur falls überhaupt bessere Punkte in den jeweiligen Kasten liegen können
        kNN_search(x, k, node.left, level + 1, sucher)
    if x[r] + sucher.best_distance[0] > node.point[r + 1] and node.right != None:
        kNN_search(x, k, node.right, level + 1, sucher)
else:
    if x[r] + sucher.best_distance[0] > node.point[r + 1] and node.right != None:
        kNN_search(x, k, node.right, level + 1, sucher)
    if x[r] - sucher.best_distance[0] <= node.point[r + 1] and node.left != None:
        kNN_search(x, k, node.left, level + 1, sucher)
```

I need the algorithm to be faster. It would be great if someone has an idea

Comment: Questions like this are better suited on [codereview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Please make sure you post a [mcve]. What is `sucher`? How is `best_distance()` implemented? How is `best_point()` implemented? Have you used a profiler to see where the time is consumed?